Unable to access local Node.js server externally
I've set up a local Node.js server using Express, and I'm trying to make it accessible from outside my local network. Here are the details of my setup:

I'm using the following code for my Node.js server:
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src')));

app.post('/click', (req, res) => {
const user = req.body; 
console.log('new user: ', user);
res.sendStatus(200); 
});

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
res.json(users);
});

app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


I've configured my router to forward external port 3000 to my local machine on port 3000.

I've created a rule in my firewall to allow incoming connections on port 3000.


When I try to access the server using my public IP (e.g., http://<your-public-ip>:3000), I get a "This site can't be reached" error.
Accessing the server locally using http://localhost:3000 works perfectly fine.
I'm using DHCP for my network connection.
I have confirmed that my public IP is reachable and that the server is running.
I also checked if there are any additional firewall settings on my router that might be blocking the connection.
